# Check scanf formating without conversions

Tags: c++, c, scanf

Is there a way how to check if some specific characters were given on input using scanf without using character conversions?

```
int main(void)
{
if(scanf("{ ["))
    printf("GOOD INPUT\n");
else
    printf("BAD INPUT\n");
return 0;
}
```

This code always gives the bad input option (it expects scanf return value to be 1) but interestingly if I enter other than the desired characters it gives the bad input imediately but if I enter it as its specified in the scanf it blows the bad input at me AFTER I enter the whole input.

So it must be awaiting the input to be in that specified format but my question is: How can I check it, without any conversions, and make according action depending on wether the input was entered correctly or not?

Comment: Read the input into something and then compare it.

Comment: Yea that is an option but what if the input can be in two possible formats and I have two scanf functions and I need to decide which one to use based on the format of the input?

Comment: Read the input first regardless of its actual format, and then compare the contents of the input against the formats you need.

Comment: Does the character between "{" and "[" need to be exactly 1 `' '` for _good_ input?

Comment: No for my purpose one space is enough important part is the order of the characters for example scanf("{ [ , :") and I want to compare it to lets say this scanf("{ [ : ,") and decide what to do next in my program based on the order of these characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` (and cousins) returns a count of the number of successful conversions. If you specify 0 conversions, then its return value will always be 0.

To use `scanf` for this task, I'd probably use a couple of scanset conversions:

```
char a[2], b[2];
if (scanf("%1[{] %1[[]", &a, &b) == 2)
    printf("Matched");
```

Or, you could simplify this a little bit:

```
char a[2];
if (scanf("{ %1[[]", &a) == 1)
```

Either way, we've specified each scan set to match only one specified character, but it's still a conversion, so we can see whether it succeeded or failed.

Unfortunately, we still have to assign the result somewhere. `scanf` does support using `*` like this: "%*s", to tell it to read a string, but not store the result anywhere--but when you do so, that conversion doesn't get counted in the return value, so (much like before) we can't use it to determine whether we got a match or not.

Answer (score 3):

You might use the `%n` conversion of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (it sets below into `pos` the number of characters read so far)

```
int pos= -1;
if (scanf("{ [%n", &pos) >=0 && pos>0) 
   printf("GOOD INPUT\n");
else 
   printf("BAD INPUT");
```

Beware, the return count of `scanf` might be implementation specific (it probably stays at 0). But  `pos` get assigned to a positive offset of `scanf` did get `{` followed by some (zero or more) space-like characters followed by a `[`.

However, what you probably want is some [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), then  `scanf` is not a good solution. You'll better read the entire line (e.g. with `fgets` or [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)) and parse it later.

See also the `man` page of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: The return  of `scanf()` is not needed here.  `pos = -1; scanf("{ [%n", &pos); if (pos>0) ...` is sufficient.

Comment: Only because I initialized `pos` to -1

Answer (score 2):

If *good* input needs to exactly 3 characters: <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>, use `"%*1[ ]"` to scan a space and `"%n"`, which saves the scan character count, to insure scanning reach the expected end.

```
int main(void) {
  int n = -1;
  scanf("{%*1[ ][%n", *n);
  if (n >= 0) {
    printf("GOOD INPUT\n");
  } else {
    printf("BAD INPUT\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'd recommend to read a *line* of input with `fgets()` first and then parse the buffer.  That can leave `stdin` in a better known state when *bad* input happens.